# How to links field value from django and extjs field using REST API

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, sencha-touch, extjs5

I have 4 forms, which called to the main view by buttons through controller.

How I must to link fields of forms with Django database, through REST api?

For example I have `form`:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.forms.RenterData', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    title: 'Renter',
    header: {
        cls: 'header-cls'
    },
    xtype: 'foresto-renterdata',
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: true,
    tools: [{
        type: 'minimize',
        handler: function() {
            this.up("panel").hide();
        }
    }, {
        type: 'save'
    }, {
        type: 'close',
        handler: function() {
            this.up("panel").close();
        }
    }],

    requires: ['Foresto.view.forms.RenterType'],

    url: 'save-form.php',

    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        labelWrap: true,
        required: true,
        afterLabelTextTpl: [
            '<span style="color:red;font-weight:normal" data-qtip="Required">*</span>'
        ]
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'foresto-rentertype',
        label: 'Type',
        name: 'rentertype'
    }, {
        xtype: 'selectfield',
        label: 'Document',
        name: 'document',

    }, {
        label: 'Document number',
        name: 'document_num'
    }, {
        label: 'NAME',
        name: 'name_represent'
    }, {
        label: 'Position',
        name: 'position_represent'
    }]
});
```

And values of

```
 name: 'document'
```

From Django:

```
{"license","rent agreement","order", "ticket"}
```

Where I can to add api url? I have to create proxy store or I can add api into form?

Please help! thanks!